# Can I return the id string of an edit text in code?

Tags: android, android-edittext

Can I get this string in code?

`GetId()` returns an int?

[image]

EDIT:

If not, is there a way I can assign my textboxes a tag each, which is a string, and then return this in code?

Comment: getId() returns an int because its a constant stored in R.class, using this int you can access it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I get this string in code?

No. You can get only `ID` of resource. Reason is because your `R.class` storing all resources as

```
public static final int fields
```

Your `R.java` can looks similar like this:

```
public static final class id {
        public static final int DataHallTextField=0x7f09000a;
}
```

### Update:

> If not, is there a way I can assign my textboxes a tag each, which is
>   a string, and then return this in code?

So i think you are looking for this:

```
String name = getResources().getResourceEntryName(R.id.DataHallTextField);
```

If you want also package you can use

```
String name = getResources().getResourceName(R.id.DataHallTextField);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the resource name:

```
getResources().getResourceEntryName(intresid);
```

If you want the resource name include package name then use:

```
getResources().getResourceName(intresid);
```